Spin of particles and bodies, is it in any way restricted i axis apart from being affected by gravity, electric fields
So I was trying to grasp how particles  or dipoles travelling in space, rather the universe might be affected and whether the spin can be stopped/ varied by the fields they interact therewith. Also whether there is a form of potential spin energy where spin could be stored and restored. I am assuming that the axis of spin of a particle has basically no restriction on axis position in space unless  affectd by a field condition.

Particle spin is an intrinsic property of the particles, they aren't actually spinning or revolving on an axis. You might want to clear that misconception first.
